# Are there any hand gestures local to Korea that are considered rude?

Tags: non-verbal-communication, offensive

As far as I know, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_finger is understood in Korea as a rude gesture much as it is in the rest of the world. However, some regions have more locally-understood gestures - e.g. the 'V-sign' in the UK.

Are there any hand gestures a foreigner might not be aware of that they should be careful not to make?

Comment: I was told that pointing your elbows at someone was considered rude.  Although I haven't had that confirmed by anyone from Korea.

Comment: I think it might be rude to pat someone on the head, or touch the top of there head. Whereas in some places this might be considered endearing.

Answer (score 3):

It's rude for someone to thrust one finger at someone's face.
[Here are some pictures.](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%EC%82%BF%EB%8C%80%EC%A7%88&rlz=1C1CHZL_koKR714KR714&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGw5TdmPrWAhWGvI8KHUgtCP8Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=_)

Comment: In which country is this not rude? Is this acceptable in Western countries?

Comment: 한국인이 가장 민감하게 받아들이는 손 제스쳐에 대해서 이야기한 것일 뿐이에요! 오히려 ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_finger) 이런 제스쳐는 나이드신 한국인 분들은 잘 모르는 경우도 많아요

Answer (score 2):

The only pretty rude finger gesture which is unique in Korea that I think of is putting your thumb between your index and middle finger. It means "fxxk you".

https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=image&sm=tab_jum&query=%EA%B2%80%EC%A7%80+%EC%A4%91%EC%A7%80+%EC%82%AC%EC%9D%B4+%EC%97%84%EC%A7%80#imgId=naverkin2001%7C214855471_0&vType=rollout

As far as I understand, it's rude in some other countries, but I am not 100% sure which countries.

Comment: Amusingly it even has an English name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fig_sign

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm allowed to post it here though...

(hidden for potentially offensive picture)

> [image: 살인의 추억 송강호 감자 먹이기]

> [image: 살인의 추억 송강호 감자 먹이기]

I found a [QNA](https://www.bobaedream.co.kr/view?code=strange&No=1818197) which explains the meaning of this gesture.

> 영화 `살인의 추억`에서 `송강호`가 했던 손가락욕이요
> 검지 밑에 엄지를 넣는
>
> 어떤 의미며 ? 정확한 명칭이 뭔가요 그건?

> 하~~아 ..
>
> 욕 잘 안흐는데 갈챠드릴라니 혀야것네잉
>
> `좢까쒸뻴너마`
>
> `좢이나 까좝솨~~~~~~~~~~~~`
>
> 입니다......